# SQLite not working with criteria in Yii

Tags: php, regex, sqlite, yii, criteria

This is my criteria code:

```
if ($this->title)
{
     $criteria->select = '*';
     $criteria->addCondition('title regexp :regexp');
     $criteria->params = array(':regexp'=>'[[:<:]]'.$this->title.'[[:>:]]');
}
```

When i'm connecting with db by MySQL in localhost, filtering wokrs fine, but when i'm using

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'sqlite:protected/data/blog.db',
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),
```

then i get this message window always when trying to filtering in CGridView.
[image]

Comment: try uppercase `REGEXP`

Comment: if you mean `title REGEXP :regexp`, not working :-(